# Don't wait to load page SELENIUM

Tags: python, forms, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I need to automate the steps in a website. But to do this with Selenium takes 18 seconds but if I do this manualy, it takes 5 seconds.
I think that in selenium do for example find any element, it waits for the page to fully load.

```
inputElement = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-email")
inputElement.send_keys('xxxx@gmail.com')
inputElement = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login-password")
inputElement.send_keys('xxxx')
inputElement.submit()
driver.find_element(By.ID,"advanced").click()
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/a/button")
button.cilck()
```

Are there any solution for this problem?

Are there another way to do it without use selenium? I mean, without use chrome.

Comment: Did you tried replacing `xpath` with `ID` as a locator strategy for the button and then observed the performance?

Comment: When you launch the site through selenium, after 5 seconds it visually looks the same as when you launch it yourself?